# what is the difference between `-- <package-name@version> and +-- <package-name@version>?

Tags: npm

When I run the command: npm list -g --depth=0
The following output is obtained:

output in cmd admin mode

[image: 1]

here 2 packages are listed with +-- while another is listed as `--
what is it telling me about that package?

Here 2 packages are listed with +-- while another is listed as `--
what is it telling me about that package?

Answer (score 0):

I think the `+--` indicates that the package is a top-level dependency. When there is **no** `+`, just `--`, it is a sub-dependency of another package.